# want to get an animated container small again to initial size with a click. It expands perfectly but I can't close it again

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

## want to get an animated container small again to initial size with a click. It expands perfectly but I can't close it again.............................................................................................................................

```
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                          width: isTextOpen ? 200 : 95,
                          height: 50,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
                            border: isTextOpen
                                ? Border.all(
                                    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                                    width: 1.0,
                                  )
                                : null,
                          ),
                          child: isTextOpen
                              ? TextField()
                              : GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      isTextOpen = true;
                                      kapaac = 1;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    "User_007",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                        ),
```

Comment: hi, you need to call isTextOpen = !isTextOpen in setstate.

and you must init istextopen false as default

başkan hep true vermişsin isTextOpen'a. Yani her tıkladığında expande etmeye çalışıyor. expand edilmişse false, expand edilmemişse true olmalı.

Comment: hi its already int isTextopen is false. Baskan ben de false zaten tam anlayamadım çok yeniyim kodlamada

Comment: I know but you need to replace istextOpen = true to isTextOpen = !isTextOpen...abi istextopen = true yazan yeri istextOpen = !istextOpen olarak değiştir düzelcek :)

Comment: I already changed that also from the previous comment :) Still The expanded container doesn't shrink to initial size. Onu yapmıştım zaten başkası aşağıda yazmış da düzelmedi valla :(

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting it back to false.

```
setState(() => isTextOpen = !isTextOpen);
```

Comment: Apologies I am really new. Exactly where should I put ur code?

Comment: Inside your onTap, replace isTextOpen = true; with isTextOpen = !isTextOpen;

Comment: Thanks, I tried but nothing changed. It was already false.

Answer (score 0):

Once the user clicks the textbox if you want to get the textBox size to the initial size then you need to define a double variable with the expanded size then once the user clicks the text box for entering the text you need to reset the variable

```
  double animatedContainerSize = 200;
```

After that set your AnimatedContainer widget width with the variable

```
  width: isTextOpen ? animatedContainerSize : 95,
```

Then in your text box onTap function change the size to initial size with setState

```
  isTextOpen
      ? TextField(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              animatedContainerSize = 95;
            });
          },
  )
```

Comment: I couldn't manage to write double animatedContainerSize = 200; anywhere. Where should I put first it doesn't accept

Comment: You should write that above the build method